# @Html.Partial Throws CS1513: } expected Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

I've researched multiple other questions on the error `CS1513: } expected`, none of which have helped.

I'm trying to introduce a partial view to a view in C# MVC 5.2.

I'm using the razor syntax `@Html.Partial("MyPartialView")` and have also tried `@{ Html.RenderPartial("MyPartialView"); }` to no avail.

When executing the code I receive the error within the view that contains the render helper on the line where I'm trying to include the partial view.

If I paste the partial view into the main view, the error does not occur which is what's confusing me as there's definitely no curly braces missing.

Here's a sample of the code:

**Main View**

```
@model ProjectBagel.Models.BagelMania

@using(Html.BeginForm("SomeAction", "SomeController", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <fieldset>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NormalBagel, new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NormalBagel, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, })

        @Html.Partial("EvenTastierBagels") //Error here - MVC doesn't like a tastier bagels :-(

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LessTastierBagel, new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LessTastierBagel, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, })

    </fieldset>
}
```

**Partial View**

```
@model ProjectBagel.Models.SuperAwesomeBagelMania

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SuperAwesomeBagel, new { @class = "control-label" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SuperAwesomeBagel, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, })
```

Can anyone suggest what the issue may be?

---

Disclaimer: I neither sell or otherwise endorse bagels.

Comment: @model = ProjectBagel... should be `@model ProjectBagel..` (no equals sign)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry, too many bagels this morning... Have edited the sample as this is right in the project!

Comment: I suspected it was a typo. I guess those SuperAwesomeBagel aren't so _super awesome_ after all :)

Comment: @{ Html.RenderPartial("_yourPartial"); } You might have missed the semi colon

Comment: Try passing in a new `SuperAwesomeBagelMania()` object

Comment: @AydinAdn Thanks for the suggestion, tried to no avail :-(

Comment: Is the last comma a typo as well in your partial view (like the 4th last character in your example) ?

Comment: @MajorByte No, according the MS docs, it should be there when using `htmlAttributes`. See: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes#new-features

Comment: i use your code,there is nothing wrong.paste some more

Comment: Your using `@Html.Partial("EvenTastierBagels")` - i.e. just adding the partial name and not passing the model, which means by default this should be passing the instance of the main model (type of `BagelMania`) to the partial, but the partial expects a model which is typeof `SuperAwesomeBagelMania`. Therefore your code should actually be throwing a different exception. Are you sure you have shown the correct code?

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke This isn't the exact code as there's 1000+ lines in the views so reluctant to dump them all here (if it is a silly syntax error). I'll have a look into the model issue a bit more thanks

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for the pointer, I wasn't passing the model in with the view and have sorted with something along the lines of `@Html.Partial("EvenTastierBagels", Model.SuperAwesomeBagelMania)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, I wasn't passing the view model to the view:

```
@Html.Partial("EvenTastierBagels", Model.BagelMania.SuperAwesomeBagelMania)
```